# ASP.NET MVC application getting binding redirect settings from app.config, not web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, app-config

I have an MVC application that I was trying to upgrade packages for, and ran into a binding redirect warning:

> Warning        Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file:  Igloo.Like  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 1819

Clicking the error and adding the binding redirect seems to have no effect.

When I looked inside the project's `Web.config` file, I see that the node indicated is present and there are no issues. However, I noticed that, for some reason, the project *also* has an `app.config` file, and *this* file still had the old `6.0.0.0` binding redirect for `Newtonsoft.Json`. Replacing that version with `7.0.0.0` fixed the issue. Deleting the config file and removing it from the project does not help; something is very stuck on `app.config`.

How do I change the configuration file and tell my application to only use `Web.config`? How does MSBuild decide to use `app.config`?

I don't know how to reduce this into a reproduction that I can share. If anyone has insight on how to do so, I will gladly do that!

Comment: do you have also an packages.config?

Comment: Yes. No reference to either `app.config` or `web.config` in it, though. Just a list of NuGet packages.

Answer (score 1):

`Web.Config` is used for asp.net web projects / web services.

`App.Config` is used for Windows Forms, Windows Services, Console Apps and WPF applications

I think you can safety move all info from `app.config` to `web.config`

Comment: That's what I thought too, but if I move everything from `app.config` to `web.config`, it breaks.